# in eines jeden Herzen

Tags: genitive, demonstrative-pronoun

This was an episode name of my favorite series. It means "in each of our hearts". It looks weird to me. Why isn't it:

> in einem jeder Herzen

or:

> im Herzen jedes Menschen

My friend has recommended this one:

> im Herzen eines jeden Menschen

So I thought it has something to do with "**ein jeder**", but I couldn't find any source explaining its grammar properly. It would be mean a lot to me if you guys can help me with it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"ein jeder" is just a way of saying "everyone" or "each one", see
[here](https://context.reverso.net/%C3%BCbersetzung/deutsch-englisch/und+ein+jeder)

- Nominative : ein jeder
- **Genitive : eines jeden**
- Dative : einem jeden
- Accusative : einen jeden

**"in eines jeden Herzen" means "in everyone's heart".**

Your friend is right, you can add "Mensch", it is sort of implied: "ein jeder" = "ein jeder Mensch"

---

An equivalent (but a bit more archaic) expression is "ein jeglicher":

Luther Bible

> und jedermann ging, dass er sich schätzen ließe, ein jeglicher in seine Stadt.

King James Bible

> And all went to be taxed, every one into his own city.

---

Note:
"In each of our hearts" close but not quite, it is not just ours but everybody's hearts.

"In einem jeder Herzen" does not make sense.

"Im Herzen jedes Menschen" and "Im Herzen eines jeden Menschen" are fine as synonyms for "In eines jeden Herzen".

Comment: I think it would be useful to add that _ein jeder_ is a more elevated style than _jeder Mensch_, as well as the fact that a preceding genitive gives a definitely archaising, at least poetic character to the wohle phrase.

Answer (score 0):

Lets rip this apart:

*In eines jeden **Herzen*** is actually accusative (*Herzen* is an archaic way to express the accusative) rather than  dative as you seem to assume.

"In" + accusative should be translated with "into", rather than "in".

"Eines jeden" is in fact the genitive of "ein jeder", so the whole expression translates to

> Into everyone's heart

Comment: Why not dative?

Comment: @DavidVogt: Ich kann den Dativ mangels Kontext nicht ausschließen, z. B. Heine "Verdroßnen Sinn im kalten Herzen hegend" [alte Rechtschreibung]

Comment: @tofro Do you have a citation for _Herzen_ being an archaic accusative form?